# How to register in new database when create an account as a guest checkout in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, php, onepage-checkout

I am using magento with another php site.when a user register or login in magento user will register or login in php site also and vice versa.

but when user checkout as a guest and check the box "create an account for later use" it will create an account in magento only.I want to register the same user in php site also.

I am using onepage checkout method.Can anybody tell me which file or function i have to edit for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982210/how-to-access-magento-customers-session-from-outside-magento?lq=1

Comment: @B00MER. Please summarize the answer in the link you posted and add it as an answer in here.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should hook into the event "customer_save_after", then you could also save the updates which the users do on their data...

```
<events>
    <customer_save_after>
        <observers>
            <your_event_identifier>
               <class>customClassIdentifer/observer</class>
               <method>afterSave</method>
            </your_event_identifier>
        </observers>
    </customer_save_after>
</events>
```

there you can get the customerdata with:

```
$customerModel = $event->getObserver()->getObjectData();
```

and save it in the other Database...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enter in `.domain.com` in Magentos admin->system->configuration->web->cookie domain. You will need to make the cookie available to your other subdomains in order for it to be read. This is the same with all web applications.

Reference:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/web#session_cookie_management_field_descriptions